# ROS Answers SE migration: Subscriber ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can a subscriber subscribe to two topics messages in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232950/subscriber-ros/) by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just create two subscribers. They can have the same callback function assuming the message types are the same.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on 2016-05-10**:
Thanks. It worked for me.